# ActionListener doesn't work properly after drawing line in java

Tags: java, drawing, line, jbutton, actionlistener

I have a problem with an action listener after I draw a line, basicly it works just one time, for example, my application is downloading an image, than u pick two points, first with left button mouse, second with right button, than u click "connect points" button, and it is drawing a line. And this works, I can do it with many lines etc. BUT when I close an window with image and reload it the "connect points" button stops working. Dk what to do with it. Here is the code:

the painting line part:

```
public void paint(Graphics g) {

 super.paint(g);
    myPaint(g);  
 }

 private void myPaint(Graphics g) {
    g.drawLine(lx1, ly1, px2, py2);
 }
}
```

ActionListener part:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

    if(e.getSource()==painterka){

       Graphics g = imadzysko.getGraphics();
          paint(g);
            lx1=0;
            ly1=0;
            px2=0;
            py2=0;    
       }
 }
```

Panel with graphic part:

```
void diagramKY (JFrame windower, String tyt, String content) {
    Listener listener = new Listener(); 

    panelik.setLayout(null);
    painterka =  new JButton("Connect Points");
    windower = new JFrame("");
    windower.setTitle(tyt+" - diagram");
    windower.setSize(800, 600);
    windower.setVisible(true);
    windower.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    URLdownloader.fileUrl("http://stooq.pl/c/?s="+content+"&c=1d&t=l&a=lg",
             content+".png","");
    imadzysko = new ImagePanel(new ImageIcon(content+".png").getImage());
    panelik.add(imadzysko);
    panelik.add(painterka);
    imadzysko.addMouseListener(new MyMouseListener());
    painterka.addActionListener(listener);
    Insets insets = panelik.getInsets();
    Dimension size = imadzysko.getPreferredSize();
    imadzysko.setBounds(20 + insets.left, 20 + insets.top,
        size.width, size.height);
    size = painterka.getPreferredSize();
    painterka.setBounds(630 + insets.left, 20 + insets.top,
        size.width, size.height);
    panelik.repaint();
    imadzysko.repaint();
    windower.add(panelik);
```

well, any suggestions? :)

Comment: *any suggestions? :)*  For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://pscode.org/sscce.html).  ;)

Comment: Also, in code snippets *or* self-contained examples.  1) Use the code formatting button.  2) Use a consistent & logical indent.  Code indenting is intended to help people understand the flow or a program, and that source reads like a dog's breakfast. 3) remove redundant white space lines.  E.G. there is no need for 3 blank lines after `py2=0;`.

Comment: Any reason you have windower as a parameter? The first thing you do is to overwrite it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) create panel, put that to the GUI and last code lines would be

```
windower.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
windower.setVisible(true);
```

otherwiese your panel never will be visible on the screen

2) don't use setBounds() etc.., for that is there exists [LayoutManagers](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html)

```
windower.add(panel);
```

then your panel fill whole JFrame area

3) never use `paint(Graphics g)` in the Swing Code, use only `paintComponent(Graphics g)` to avoids un-expected output to the GUI

4) don't create new [Top-level Containers](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/toplevel.html) on Runtime, for popup window create only one JDialog or JWindow and re-use that for another Action

5) you have problems with [Concurency in Swing](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html), your GUI freeze, because waiting for hard and longtime code, implements [SwingWorker](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/simple.html), there is similair example about that

6) if you want to display some pictures or images look for [Icon](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/icon.html) placed in the [JLabel](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/label.html)

7) really required to read [2D Graphics](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/index.html) tutorial before posting question here

Comment: ad 3. paintComponent(Graphics g) doesn't work at all, it won't draw even one line. pain(Graphics g) works. 
ad 2. Why can't I use absolute positioning? It's more handy to me, I can put everything exactly where I want.

ad 6. why the ImagePanel is wrong solution for displaying picture?

thanks for answers

Comment: `add.2` for example your contents is non-resiziable ... `add 3.` not true at all, don't, never do that, forgot for code from lots of Java Examples Depots, `add6` read tutorial about Icon and JLabel

Comment: ad3 ad3 :). I have check befere I post here, paintComponent doesn't work at all, IN MY CASE :)

Comment: around us is lots of examples how to DrawLine, DrawLine from Action,  change `java.awt.Panel` to the `java.swing.JPanel`

Answer (score 1):

```
Graphics g = imadzysko.getGraphics();
```

Never do that.  A Java GUI should paint when told to do so.  When that time comes, the `paint(Graphics)` or `paintComponent(Graphics)` will be called.  Do the painting then.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand, without this line drawing doens't work.

Comment: @Donw-Voter, can post a reason, this short answer batter and confortly covered 4.points from my answer